# K8S Audit Sink - does it handle retry?

Tags: kubernetes, audit-logging

I am using auditSink object in order to get the audit logs.
I didn't find any documentation/api regarding retry option for audit logs.
What happens in case the web server / service is not available?

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/#auditsink-v1alpha1-auditregistration-k8s-io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The fine source](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.18.3/staging/src/k8s.io/apiserver/plugin/pkg/audit/dynamic/factory.go#L34) implies there is a retry mechanism, and thus the need for configuring its backoff, but aside from whatever you can find by surfing around in the source, I don't know that any promises have been made about deliverability. If you need such guarantees, you may be happier sending audit event to stdout or to disk and then egressing them the way you would with any other log content